# Intuitive understanding of tangents vectors on a neighbourhood

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

Let $U := B_2(0)$ be the unit ball. Then, the tangent space at $(0,0.5)$ is defined by

$$ T_{(0,0.5)} U = \{ \text{all } \mathbb R^2 \text{ arrows emanating from } (0,0.5) \}. $$

How does this definition makes sense? How can any vector be tangent to some point in the interior of U? And over all, why are ALL vectors emanating from $(0,0.5)$ tangent? My - so far - naive understanding of tangent vectors is that they emanate only of the boundary and that only one/some vectors are tangent but assuredly not all - i.e. arbitrary - vectors.

How does this work when we consider arbitrary neighbourhoods? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might help to first visualize the situation when you consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a subset of  $\mathbb{R}^3$ first. Then if you fix the point $(0,0.5,0)$ and draw an arrow emanating from that point in an arbitrary direction, wouldn't you say it's tangent to the point and to the whole $x-y$ plane? I think this should be intuitive to you. Also the definition you gave is only a heuristic definition and isn't quite general. In an arbitrary smooth manifold you may not even have the notion of "arrows" hence a more complicated definition (but an intuitive one nonetheless) is required.

Comment: The normalized tangent vectors define all the directions from a given point. Since the ball is three-dimensional there are three dimensions worth of directions that can be taken. On a two dimensional surface, this would be a circle's worth of directions and on a curve (1-manifold) you only have one dimension's worth of directions.

Answer (score 1):

Tangent vectors tell you all the directions (and speeds) you can travel while staying within the manifold. Nothing more, nothing less.

If you were travelling in $U$ - you cannot leave it - and you happen to pass through $(0,0.5)$, what possible velocities could you have at that moment? Ignoring any physical limitations you could be travelling at any speed, and you could be heading in any possible direction in the plane.

Thinking of the tangent space as being vectors on the "boundary" presupposes that $U$ is sitting inside some larger dimensional space. When it is (such as when you consider $\Bbb R^2$ to be a plane in $\Bbb R^3$), then the points of $U$ are all on
the boundary. And the directions *tangent* to $U$ are the velocities you can have while moving constrained to $U$. So you cannot move in directions in that third dimension, because that is not a direction into which $U$ extends.

But manifolds are to be considered a thing unto themselves, not subsets of some larger space. $U$ need not even be considered a subset of $\Bbb R^2$, but rather just some 2-dimensional space all of its own. The tangent space at any given point of $U$ still exists. It is still a 2-dimensional vector space that includes all possible velocities that a smooth curve could have while passing through the point. It is 2-dimensional because $U$ is 2-dimensional. At any point, all possible directions you can go in $U$ can be described as combinations of just two directions.